# Is there any limitation of number of shards in Mongodb cluster?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I heard that it's a good practice to maintain data < 50% of HDD size. What if my data grow too fast and I have to add more shard to the cluster. Is there any limitation of number of shards? If there is, what is the ideal number?

Comment: Nope, you could have, like facebook, 32,000 (last figures I looked at) if you want

Comment: I doubt fb uses mongodb ;)

Comment: No they use Cassandra and MySQL, so they have 32,000 MySQL shards

Comment: @Sammaye- the question was about mongodb though?

Comment: Try [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @WiredPrairie well considering that MySQL had sharding built ontop and MongoDB had it built in, not only that but directly speaking about MongoDB I said no, I used facebook as a comparison

Comment: @Sammaye - don't understand your comparison ... but OK.

Comment: @WiredPrairie the comparison is that you can have just as many databse shards as facebook, aka a very big site